# padding in not working properly in small and medium device bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

in desktop i add '50px' padding in my page body.and its working properly but in small and medium its not working properly.yes i add some bootstrap function means @media css functionality.but although its not working.

my html=>

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="content-wrapper px-auto MainRenderedbody">
        <section class="content">
            render body
        </section>
    </div>

    render partial body
</div>
```

and my css=>

```
<style type="text/css">
@@media (min-width: @@screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @@screen-sm-max) {
    .MainRenderedbody {
        padding-top:100px;
    }
}
.MainRenderedbody {
    padding-top:45px;
}
</style>
```

i search about this problem? and i found some solution.i apply all of theme? nut nothing works for me? thats why i re posted this kind of problem in this website again!!!

picture of desktop screen=>
[image]

and small screen=>
[image]

Look the about 'DELETE Batch' Gone already ? but i wants it back by adding some extra padding ? and another trick? please help me to solve this problem?or give me some suggestion ? expert brothers please help?

Comment: I think your 'Delete Batch is behind your bottom navigation bar'. Trying doing an 'Inspect Element' on your missing text.

Comment: @Nivedita yes it behind the navigation bar ? whats i need to do to bring it visible?

Comment: AFAIK, `@@media` is invalid. You should not double the `@`s (unless you have a pre-processor that turns them it into the correct `@media` query tags).

Comment: is your nav bar fixed at the top ?

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu   Sorry to Say I am Working On a rozar .net thats why it needs a extra @..this is not invalid

Comment: @Nivedita yes it is fixed...

Comment: What are the values of `@screen-sm-min` and `@screen-sm-max`? Have you tried with hard coded values to see if it works? Normally you don't put a `min-width` for mobile. Just `max-width` (usually 767px).

Comment: I think you need to add some margin to your container for medium and small devices

Comment: Can you create a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Get your output HTML and resulting CSS and create a fiddle, like Nivedita suggested. @Nivedita, technically speaking, `padding` works in more cases than `margin`, because margin has a few cases where it gets ignored, but padding will always be respected. The only way to cancel padding is to change the children (pos absolute or negative margins).  I don't think how switching to `margin` would make a difference here.

Comment: `    @media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        .MainRenderedbody {
            padding-top: 100px;
        }
    }`

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu still not working.....

Comment: `(min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 767px)` only applies at 767px! Remove the min and it will work. It's plain English!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu "    @@media (max-width: 767px) {
        .MainRenderedbody {
            padding-top: 100px;
        }
    }"

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu still not working....

Answer (score 0):

your script already hide the `Delete Batch` on `sm` small sreen.

```
   1. Inspect your missing `<div>`.
   2. Then identify where the `div` hides.
   3. `remove` that `class` name.
   4. you wrote your own `class` to view it in `@media`

 @media screen and (min-width: 650px){
      .className
      {
        padding-top:100px;
      }
    }
```